# Projects not appearing in "gcloud projects list"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I added a project in to the google cloud console, but that project isn't appearing using the gcloud SDK "gcloud projects list"

Am I doing something silly or have I missed something?

Edit:

1. Are you using different credentials for the new account?
   No, the account is the same account logged in both the console and on the sdk console
2. Are you using organizations?
   No, no organisation

Comment: Are you logged into the correct account?  Have you waited a minute or two for the project to appear?

Comment: @GlenCarpenter I am yes, same account on the console and the SDK, and I've left it an hour and it's not updated

Comment: @JohnHanley Edited

Comment: Does the new project and previous projects show up in the Google Cloud Console?

Comment: For the new project, what IAM roles do you have?

Comment: @JohnHanley All projects show in the console yes

Comment: What does `gcloud projects describe PROJECT_ID` show for the new Project ID?

Comment: @JohnHanley that shows:
createTime: '2020-11-13T18:28:55.614Z'
lifecycleState: ACTIVE
(plus some details about the project)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224540/discussion-between-paul-and-john-hanley).

Comment: Since `describe` work, this means you can `read` access the project. I am guessing there is a temporary issue or delay with Google Cloud.

Comment: @JohnHanley Ok, I'll leave it till tomorrow and see if it appears.  Want to publish something to it from visual studio but doesn't appear in there either.  Weird!  Thanks

Comment: @Paul, can you please try running the following command and let us know about the results? (gcloud projects list --verbosity debug)  --- Note: Please don't share your personally identifiable information (PII) information on this portal such as your project id etc, and redact before sharing the results of command (gcloud projects list --verbosity debug)

Comment: It's showing this morning...must just be a reeeeally long delay