# Google Cloud: Unable to see the project

Tags: cloud, project, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I am unable to see the project which I have created using `gcloud projects create` command

Couple of points to be considered:

a. I am using the trial account and based out of India.

b. Its standalone project created using below command.

```
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud projects create projectidudemylearning --name=projectudemylearning
```

c. Only one account is being used throughout.

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud auth list
      Credentialed Accounts
    ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
    *       xxxx@gmail.com

    To set the active account, run:
        $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
```

d. The `gcloud projects describe` shows the below details:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud projects describe projectidudemylearning
    createTime: '2023-07-18T04:10:19.446Z'
    lifecycleState: ACTIVE
    name: projectudemylearning
    projectId: projectidudemylearning
    projectNumber: '623629744110'
```

e. The project is also not visible in https://cloud.google.com.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Did you receive a Google Cloud email about the new project?

Comment: No John, there is no email. Also I went through your comments on "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64826856/projects-not-appearing-in-gcloud-projects-list".

Comment: You might be experiencing a delay in seeing the project. From the screenshot, I can see that you created the new project about two hours ago. Edit your post with details. Are you a new account? Standalone project or Organization? Where are you in the world? What is the result from `gcloud projects describe PROJECT_ID`?

Comment: I have added the more details, hope it will help

Comment: Based on your update, the project has been created and you can access it. I think the only issue is being able to list the project. Probably in a few hours that will resolve itself. You can either use `gcloud config set project` to set the default project or specify `--project` for most commands. Double-check access using the Google Cloud Console GUI. You should be able to switch between different projects. Also check here: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager

Comment: @JohnHanley, Its displaying now, it takes around 12~24 hours to reflect the project in Dashboard/Console if project is created using SDK.